# What is the subject in a passive infinitive sentence saying "to be considered for a promotion"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, passive-voice, indirect-objects, infinitive-constructions

> Once the employees have completed the company's largest project
>   successfully, **they will be offered an opportunity to be
>   considered for a promotion.**

I found that sentence in my English book and this is a little bit confusing because I am not sure WHO consider the opportunity between the employees and the company.

First, I understand the "consider" means to contemplate giving something (often a particular job or role) to someone([Link](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/consider+(someone)+for+(something))). And to see the detail meaning, I divided the sentence into two as follows.

> a-1.The employees will be offered an opportunity + **the company
>   will consider the employees** for a promotion.
>   =a-2.The employees will be offered an opportunity + **the employees will be considered** for a promotion **by the company**.
>   =a-3.The employees will be offered an opportunity+ **to be considered** for a promotion (by the company).

I tried it like this way :

> b-1.The employees will be offered an opportunity + **the company
>   will consider an opportunity** for a promotion.
>   =b-2.The employees will be offered an opportunity + **an opportunity will be considered** for a promotion **by the company**.
>   =b-3.The employees will be offered an opportunity+ **to be considered** for a promotion (by the company).

What makes sense to me is the situation that employees will consider the opportunity like the group of sentence A. Would you please tell me which one is the right divided sentences? And if the group sentence B are right, could you explain the precise meaning of that with nuance?

Comment: What makes you think it’s a **passive** infinitive sentence? The subject of the first sentence is “employees” and the antecedent “they” (subject of “They will be offered...”) refers to “employees”. A passive sentence would mean the object of the previous sentence has become inverted to be the subject of a new sentence.

Comment: I thought 'to be ed/en' phrase is called passive infinitive and found the term from here : https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-and-imperatives/infinitive-active-or-passive Am I wrong?

Comment: This is a passive voice sentence.  No question about it.  It has an implied subject, which is the company.  The subject is not directly expressed.

Comment: @Karlomanio Are you confusing agent and subject? In neither "I was fired" nor "I was fired by the company" is _the company_ the subject.

Comment: Yes, I meant agent. Thanks @EdwinAshworth!

Comment: @Karlomanio, I don't understand the confusion. The subject is directly expressed in the first insubordinate clause: "[once] The employees have completed the company's largest project"... not, "[once] the company's largest project has been completed by the employees" therefore [one should assume the subject of the active voice throughout](https://www.uno.edu/lrc/writingcenter/documents/SHIFTS-ACTIVE-AND-PASSIVE-VOICE.pdf) despite the shift: active -> passive. I would understand the confusion if they were separate sentences.

Comment: @John Lawler what do you think? is it best to treat them as separate sentences or as clauses functioning as one sentence?

Comment: @aesking, these are two separate clauses.  "Once..." has nothing to do with the clause Jean is asking about.

Comment: @Karlomanio and I'm referring to the confusion Jean states from "I found that sentence in my English book and this is a little bit confusing because I am not sure WHO consider(s) the opportunity between the employees and the company.", it is entirely relevant to what he is asking about as this is **the sentence** he is referring to: *Once the employees have completed the company's largest project successfully, they will be offered an opportunity to be considered for a promotion*.

Comment: @aesking Sorry for the confusion.  The title states "to be considered for" and that wasn't in the clause starting with "Once...".

Comment: Note he says "What is the subject in a passive infinitive **sentence**" not clause, so I assume he was referring to the whole sentence and not that just clause. I admit I did initially confuse clause and sentence in my first comment but I treated them as "sentences/clauses" depending on each other, not as separate entities.

Comment: @Karlomanio, you get the point of my question exactly. Your answer saying the implied subject indicates the company satisfied my curiosity. Also, I appreciate all your other comments :)

Comment: @aesking Sorry for the confusion. What I was referring to is the second clause staring "they will be~." I've just realized the word 'sentence' and 'clause' are totally different words in English after reading your comment while in my mother tongue, the two words are often interchangeable. I guess that's where my mistake came from. Anyway, thanks to your opinion, I could learn exact grammatical term and I'll be more careful when choosing the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

> - *They will be offered an opportunity to be considered for a promotion*

contains two clauses: a main clause, and an infinitive clause modifying *an opportunity*. Both clauses have been modified by the Passive construction, among others, and reduced by substitution and deletion rules.

Something like an unwound expansion of this sentence might be

- *The company will offer an opportunity to the employees* -- (main clause)
  *for the company to consider the employees for a promotion.* -- (infinitive clause)
  (It doesn't sound like such an opportunity stated that way, does it?)

*The company* isn't mentioned in the passives, but it's the agent subject of both clauses, in the active.
The clauses are in the passive form because the subject is already mentioned in the preliminary subordinate clause, and because it is obvious from the employee relation mentioned.

> - *Once the employees have completed **the company**'s largest project successfully,*

After this clause, both *the company* and *the employees* can be represented by *them*. The listener is required to understand which one, but since *the company* is the agent in both clauses, making them agentless passives (applying Passive without the agent *by*-phrase) gets rid of them. Thereafter, reference to *them* in this context refers to *the employees*.

The Passive in the main clause is complicated because it involves Dative,
which is the rule that relates these two sentences, for instance:

- *The company offered an opportunity **to them**.*
- *The company offered **them** an opportunity.*

Passive applied to these two variants gives two variant of Passive:

- *An opportunity was offered **to them**.*
- ***They*** were offered an opportunity.

The Dative Passive of the second example is what happens in the main clause.

The infinitive clause loses its original agent subject by agentless Passive,

and then loses its derived *for*-phrase and the receiver (not agent) subject it introduces

- *[for them] to be considered for a promotion*

by ordinary infinitive reduction. Most infinitives lack an overt subject, either because the subject is not specific, or because (as here) it is specific, but it can be inferred from the syntax and the context.

Left unanalyzed is the predicative but not syntactic relation between *offering an opportunity* and its modifying infinitive clause -- the clause details some of the offering and some of the opportunity, and they're related in several ways; but syntactically, all one can say is that the infinitive modifies the noun phrase.

Comment: This is so great! Thank you so much for your kind explanation. I guess there are two questions to make sure that I understand you correctly.  First, in the sentence where it read : the infinitive clause loses its original agent subject by agentless Passive, the word 'its original agent subject' indicate the company, right? Second, would you please explain the definition of the receiver subject (Is it just another word for a subject?' and which one between the employees and the company is the receiver subject?

Comment: (1) Yes, the original agent subject was _the company_ (presumably; it isn't there, but that's what it means). (2) By 'receiver subject' I mean _the employees,_ since they were the (potential future) receivers of the opportunity; 'receiver' is a semantic role (in this case there are 3 argument roles for the verb: agent/source (_the company_), patient/trajector (_an opportunity_), receiver/target (_the employees_). Passive can promote the patient to subject (_an opportunity will be presented_) or, if Dative is involved, it can promote the receiver  to subject (_the employees will be offered_).